# Linq where clause with multiple conditions

Tags: linq, where-clause, conditional-statements

this method returns generic list but it has multiple condition to get select.
I'm just writing this using if - else if -else if.... so many if else i mean
Is there a shorter way to do this? Thank you.

```
    public List<ProductReqNoDate> GetRequestsQuery(string departmant, int reqStateID, string firstDate, string lastDate)
    {
        var db = new requestsDBEntities();
        var listPrn = new List<ProductReqNoDate>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(departmant))
        {
            return  (from r in db.requests
                       where r.departmant== departmant
                       select new ProductReqNoDate
                       {
                           departmant= r.departmant,
                           reqNo = r.reqNo ,
                           reqDate = r.reqDate ,
                           prdctName= stringCutter((from p in db.products where p.reqNo == r.reqNo select p.prdctName).FirstOrDefault())
                       }).ToList();

        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstDate) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastDate))
        {
            DateTime dtfirstDate = Convert.ToDateTime(firstDate);
            DateTime dtlastDate = Convert.ToDateTime(lastDate);
            return (from r in db.requests
                       where r.reqDate <= dtlastDate && r.reqDate >= dtfirstDate 
                       select new ProductReqNoDate
                       {
                           departmant= r.departmant,
                           reqNo = r.reqNo ,
                           reqDate = r.reqDate,
                           prdctName= stringCutter((from p in db.products where p.reqNo == r.reqNo select p.prdctName).FirstOrDefault())
                       }).ToList();

        }
    }
```

Comment: As linq is executed when first accessing the results, perhaps you could put the first 'from/where' into a var and then outside of the ifs, use the select new query onto the retrieved result set.

Answer (score 6):

You can have the core of your query as the following:

```
var query = from r in db.requests 
select new ProductReqNoDate
                   {
                       departmant= r.departmant,
                       reqNo = r.reqNo ,
                       reqDate = r.reqDate ,
                       prdctName= stringCutter((from p in db.products 
                      where p.reqNo == r.reqNo select p.prdctName).FirstOrDefault())
                   }
```

Then apply `if then else`:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(departmant))
    return  query.Where(r=>r.departmant== departmant).ToList();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstDate) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastDate))
{
        DateTime dtfirstDate = Convert.ToDateTime(firstDate);
        DateTime dtlastDate = Convert.ToDateTime(lastDate);
        return query.Where(r=> r.reqDate <= dtlastDate && r.reqDate >= dtfirstDate)
                    .ToList();
 }
```

It doesn't reduce `if then else` but makes more sensible, what going happens.

Comment: well actually, i need to consider so many conditions to get value... public List<ProductReqNoDate> GetRequestsQuery(string departmant, int reqStateID, string firstDate, string lastDate, string productName).... i mean if all conditions true that must give me a filtered answer. Or one of them is true,rest are false... so i need to write all possibilities?? if(a&b&c&d) else if(a&b&c) else if(a&c&d) else if(b&c&d) else if(a&b) else if (a&c)...etc ?? :)))

Comment: @blackraist, all the things I can think is making query builder class, to query expression by your condition, this way just makes your code more readable, also if it's not linq2sql you can use reflection and simple counter (in base 2) to create your query.

Answer (score 1):

1*

you can found better sollution but I wish this help (I thing) but I use it : you can make the test out this function

```
   List<ProductReqNoDate> yourList = GetRequestsQuery(string departmant, int reqStateID)

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstDate) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastDate))
    {
      yourdatagrid.Itemsource = yourList.where(a=> a.reqDate <= Datetime.parse(firstDate) & a.reqDate >= Datetime.parse(lastDate))
    }


public List<ProductReqNoDate> GetRequestsQuery(string departmant, int reqStateID)
{
    var db = new requestsDBEntities();
    var listPrn = new List<ProductReqNoDate>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(departmant))
    {
        return  (from r in db.requests
                   where r.departmant== departmant
                   select new ProductReqNoDate
                   {
                       departmant= r.departmant,
                       reqNo = r.reqNo ,
                       reqDate = r.reqDate ,
                       prdctName= stringCutter((from p in db.products where p.reqNo == r.reqNo select p.prdctName).FirstOrDefault())
                   }).ToList();

    }
}
```

and you can apply any condition in your first list but in not recommended in havy application or many information in database.

2*

Or you can just make the first date and the last date; for exemple if the date is not set,make the first date = 01/01/1900 and the last date Datetime.Today and always pass your date in the linq query

Comment: well actually, i need to consider so many conditions to get value...  public List<ProductReqNoDate> GetRequestsQuery(string departmant, int reqStateID, string firstDate, string lastDate, string productName)....  i mean if all conditions true that must give me a filtered answer. Or one of them is true,rest are false... so i need to write all possibilities?? if(a&b&c&d) else if(a&b&c) else if(a&c&d) else if(b&c&d) else if(a&b) else if (a&c)...etc ?? :)))

Answer (score 0):

something like this I haven't compiled and checked it but it should give you a clue.

```
public List<ProductReqNoDate> GetRequestsQuery(string departmant, int reqStateID, string firstDate, string lastDate)
 {
    using(var db = new requestsDBEntities())
    {

      DateTime dtfirstDate =null;
      DateTime.TryParse(firstDate,out dtfirstDate);

      DateTime dtlastDate = null;
      DateTime.TryParse(lastDate,out dtlastDate);

      var result = (from r in db.requests
                   where 
                      (r.departmant == departmant)
                   || (r.reqDate <= dtlastDate.Value && r.reqDate >= dtfirstDate.Value)
                   select new ProductReqNoDate
                   {
                       departmant = r.departmant,
                       reqNo = r.reqNo ,
                       reqDate = r.reqDate ,
                       prdctName= stringCutter((from p in db.products where p.reqNo == r.reqNo select p.prdctName).FirstOrDefault())
                   }).ToList();
    }

 }
```

EDIT:

if you want to use non-sql functions in your filter then call ToList() on your table

```
 var result = db.requests.ToList().Where(r => { 

     // do test for what you want
     // so write a function to work out when you want to filter by
     // name or date
     return true;

 }).Select( r => new ProductReqNoDate
                   {
                       departmant = r.departmant,
                       reqNo = r.reqNo ,
                       reqDate = r.reqDate ,
                       prdctName= stringCutter(db.products.Where(p=> p.reqNo == r.reqNo).Select(p=> p.prdctName).FirstOrDefault())
                   })
```

the problem with this is that you are loading the whole table into memory which if fine if you don't change to values in it often and if it's not too big.

Another approach would be to write it as a stored proc which would probably make your DBA happy.

Comment: what if all of parameters aren't null, i mean if all conditions true that must give me a filtered answer.For this approach 1 condition is enough to get value.